# Brownie Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, brownie

I'm completing the freecodecamp solidity tutorial for the advanced NFT and when deploying to a rinkeby testnet it returns:

`ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.`

When I use the fund_with_link token my contract is funded yet I'm unable to call the create_collectible function without being returned an error message. I do have enough link in my metamask account.

Here is the contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.7/VRFConsumerbase.sol";

contract AdvancedCollectible is ERC721, VRFConsumerBase {
    uint256 public tokenCounter;
    bytes32 public keyhash;
    uint256 public fee;
    enum Breed {
        PUG,
        SHIBA_INU,
        ST_BERNARD
    }
    mapping(uint256 => Breed) public tokenIdToBreed;
    mapping(bytes32 => address) requestIdToSender;
    event requestedCollectible(bytes32 indexed requestId, address requester);
    event breedAssigned(uint256 indexed tokenId, Breed breed);

    constructor(
        address _vrfCoordinator,
        address _linkToken,
        bytes32 _keyhash,
        uint256 _fee
    )
        public
        VRFConsumerBase(_vrfCoordinator, _linkToken)
        ERC721("Dogie", "DOG")
    {
        tokenCounter = 0;
        keyhash = _keyhash;
        fee = _fee;
    }

    function createCollectible(string memory tokenURI)
        public
        returns (bytes32)
    {
        bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyhash, fee);
        requestIdToSender[requestId] = msg.sender;
        emit requestedCollectible(requestId, msg.sender);
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomNumber)
        internal
        override
    {
        Breed breed = Breed(randomNumber % 3);
        uint256 newTokenId = tokenCounter;
        tokenIdToBreed[newTokenId] = breed;
        emit breedAssigned(newTokenId, breed);
        address owner = requestIdToSender[requestId];
        _safeMint(owner, newTokenId);
        tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
    }

    function setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) public {
        //need tokenId for pug, shiba-inu and st-bernard
        //making sure that only the owner of the tokenId can update the tokenURI
        require(
            _isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId),
            "ERC721: is not owner, not approved"
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the deploy script:

```
from scripts.helpful_scripts import (
    get_account,
    OPENSEA_URL,
    get_contract,
    fund_with_link,
)
from brownie import AdvancedCollectible, config, network
from web3 import Web3
from time import sleep

sample_token_uri = "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmd9MCGtdVz2miNumBHDbvj8bigSgTwnr4SbyH6DNnpWdt?filename=0-PUG.json"


def deploy_and_create():
    account = get_account()
    advanced_collectible = AdvancedCollectible.deploy(
        get_contract("vrf_coordinator"),
        get_contract("link_token"),
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["keyhash"],
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["fee"],
        {"from": account},
    )
    fund_with_link(advanced_collectible.address)
    create_collectible = advanced_collectible.createCollectible(
        sample_token_uri, {"from": account}
    )


def main():
    deploy_and_create()
```

Here is the helpful scripts:

```
from brownie import network, config, accounts, LinkToken, VRFCoordinatorMock, Contract
import dotenv
from web3 import Web3

OPENSEA_URL = "https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/{}/{}"
LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS = ["hardhat", "development", "ganache", "mainnet-fork"]


def get_account(index=None, id=None):
    if index:
        return accounts[index]
    if network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
        return accounts[0]
    if id:
        return accounts.load(id)
    return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])


contract_to_mock = {"link_token": LinkToken, "vrf_coordinator": VRFCoordinatorMock}


def get_contract(contract_name):
    """
    This function will either:
        - Get an address from the config
        - Or deploy a Mock to use for a network that doesn't have the contract
    Args:
        contract_name (string): This is the name of the contract that we will get
        from the config or deploy
    Returns:
        brownie.network.contract.ProjectContract: This is the most recently deployed
        Contract of the type specified by a dictionary. This could either be a mock
        or a 'real' contract on a live network.
    """
    # link_token
    # LinkToken
    contract_type = contract_to_mock[contract_name]
    if network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
        if len(contract_type) <= 0:
            deploy_mocks()
        contract = contract_type[-1]
    else:
        contract_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()][contract_name]
        contract = Contract.from_abi(
            contract_type._name, contract_address, contract_type.abi
        )
    return contract


def deploy_mocks():
    """
    Use this script if you want to deploy mocks to a testnet
    """
    print(f"The active network is {network.show_active()}")
    print("Deploying mocks...")
    account = get_account()
    print("Deploying Mock LinkToken...")
    link_token = LinkToken.deploy({"from": account})
    print(f"Link Token deployed to {link_token.address}")
    print("Deploying Mock VRF Coordinator...")
    vrf_coordinator = VRFCoordinatorMock.deploy(link_token.address, {"from": account})
    print(f"VRFCoordinator deployed to {vrf_coordinator.address}")
    print("All done!")


def fund_with_link(
    contract_address, account=None, link_token=None, amount=Web3.toWei(2, "ether")
):
    account = account if account else get_account()
    link_token = link_token if link_token else get_contract("link_token")
    funding_tx = link_token.transfer(contract_address, amount, {"from": account})
    funding_tx.wait(1)
    print(f"Funded {contract_address}")
    return funding_tx
```

Here is the brownie-config.yaml:

```
dotenv: .env
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1'
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
networks:
  development:
    keyhash: "0xd89b2bf150e3b9e13446986e571fb9cab24b13cea0a43ea20a6049a85cc807cc"
    fee: 100000000000000000
  rinkeby:
    vrf_coordinator: "0x6168499c0cFfCaCD319c818142124B7A15E857ab"
    link_token: "0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709"
    keyhash: "0xd89b2bf150e3b9e13446986e571fb9cab24b13cea0a43ea20a6049a85cc807cc"
    fee: 10000000000000000
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hey, I found a solution and it was just me being stupid - not surprising. I just wrote the wrong amount of zeros for the fee in the brownie-config.yaml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rinkeby network these are the address for the following parameters.
vrf_coordinator: "0xb3dCcb4Cf7a26f6cf6B120Cf5A73875B7BBc655B"

link_token: "0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709"

keyhash: "0x2ed0feb3e7fd2022120aa84fab1945545a9f2ffc9076fd6156fa96eaff4c1311"

fee: 100000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and it was just me being stupid - not surprising. I just wrote the wrong amount of zeros for the fee in the brownie-config.yaml file. Also I had the wrong eth address for the keyhash.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Seems like I have run into the same issue. Could  you post the coorect keyHash  so I can verify mine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the addresses from Chainlink VRF v1 NOT v2 in your .yaml, remember to re-deploy your contract with these newly updated addresses. Please see the link below for the addresses:

https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v1/supported-networks/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71194882/execution-reverted-during-call-this-transaction-will-likely-revert-if-you-wish